# Worked out example of Slepian-Wolf Theorem

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, encoding-scheme, entropy

*Note: First posted this on Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange, but deleted it from there since it seems to be off-topic.*

The [Slepian-Wolf](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Slepian-Wolf_coding) theorem states that sequences of outputs from two separate random variable sources A and B that have a joint probability distribution defined on them, if encoded with the following rates, can be completely retrieved when decoded together:

$$
R_A \geq H(A|B) \\
R_B \geq H(B|A) \\
R_A + R_B \geq H(A,B)
$$

$R_x$ refers to the bits required for encoding one symbol of $X$, assuming all logarithms are taken to the base 2.

Given this, I wanted to try out an example, especially because I find fractional number of bits per symbol slightly confusing to think about.

Consider two sources $A$ and $B$, that either sprout out 0 or 1 following this probability distribution:

<kbd>**`A \ B`**</kbd>   <kbd>**`0`**</kbd>    <kbd>**`1`**</kbd>  
  <kbd>**`0`**</kbd>    <kbd>`0.5`</kbd>   <kbd>`0`</kbd>  
  <kbd>**`1`**</kbd>    <kbd>`0.25`</kbd> <kbd>`0.25`</kbd>

We calculate the entropies as follows:
$$
H(A,B) = 3/2  = 15/10\\
H(A|B) = 7/10 \\
H(B|A) = 1/2 = 5/10\\
$$

Now, assume that the a certain sequence of bits that A and B give out are as follows:

<kbd>**`A`**</kbd>  <kbd>**`B`**</kbd> 
 <kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`1`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`1`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd> 
 <kbd>`0`</kbd>  <kbd>`0`</kbd>

I should be able to find an encoding that allows A to send atleast 7 bits, B atleast 5 and a total of atleast 15, such that they can be decoded completely, right?

Unfortunately I am unable to think of an encoding where they send less than 10 bits each.

For example, B does not have to send anything when A sends 0, however B does not know when A sends 0.

I would also like to know if this is the wrong way to interpret the theorem (perhaps a longer sequence is required), or if there is another way to see its working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler example. Consider the binary erasure channel which erases its input with probability $1/2$. The channel capacity is $1/2$, so you should be able to send one bit of information by sending two bits on the channel. Or should you?

Shannon's theorem only guarantees that for every $\epsilon > 0$, you can send $(1/2-\epsilon) N$ bits of information by sending $N$ bits across the channel, with failure probability approaching zero as $N\to\infty$. There are two features of this theorem (shared by Slepian–Wolf) that you didn't take into account:

- The theorem talks about asymptotic rates.
- The theorem allows for some small failure probability.

The article you link to assumes you are already aware of all this. Since you appear not to be, I suggest reading a textbook on information theory, where all the relevant concepts are defined and explained.